# Thousands of unnecessary redirects in Google Search Console going to original posts URLS

Tags: google-search-console

In Google Search Console, I noticed 7200 links in "Page with redirect" section. These links include some parts of posts' permalinks as shown in the image. Most shocking is these URLs go to the original URLS of my posts. Clicking these links opens the posts. I checked throughout the .htaccess, and codes. Couldn't figure out what was happening. Please, suggest what can I do to resolve the issue.

[image: page with redirect in google search console]

Comment: What content management system (CMS) are you using?  If not a CMS, how are your files structured?  What is the contents of your .htaccess?  An answer was posted with a guess about the cause, but without knowing a lot more about your site, there are several possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache, (and I assume other webservers as well), uses a trailing / when accessing a directory and not a file. Apache automatically redirects the request to the correct URL for a directory which includes the trailing /.

Performance-wise, since the visitor already has negotiated a connection the redirect will take place without the overhead of needing to establish a new connection but it is still a round trip. Links to websites that are not to a specific file should have the trailing slash.

https://example.com/ not https://example.com

https://example.com/category/ not https://example.com/category

for directories and

https://example.com/favicon.ico

no trailing / for files.

---

Its a minor issue because it does resolve to the correct URL. But it is not without an impact --  using up a redirect and round trip.

To fix you need to fix the pages that are linking to the URL that do not have the trailing /.

Comment: Several URLs have half or some parts of permalink and they are redirected to the correct posts. I have interlinked many posts so there was a chance that URLs there might be incorrectly inserted. I checked many posts thoroughly and found them correct. Now I am confused about where these links are coming from. Here is doubt on old redirect plugins that were used in long past. They may keep leftovers in the database.

Comment: Clicking on the inspect, (magnification icon), brings up an inspect URL for that page ... It may resolve the mystery of where and when the version without the / was discovered.

Comment: Inspected and found that the Referring pages are external sites (different for different URLs). In some cases, "None detected" is reported.

Comment: It was the case of changed permalink. I used the function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012014/wordpress-automatically-created-a-redirect-that-i-need-removed and everything got settled. Thanks for support and be with me until then.